# install4j: Setup shows error message box with text for "LastRunFailed"

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j setup (for Windows) and when I run it (Win 8, x86) I get an error message dialog with the message which is defined by "LastRunFailed", e.g. in English:

> The installer did not start up correctly on the last run.\nThis is
>   probably caused by a corrupted Java VM.\nDo you want to download or
>   manually select the JVM?"

I could solve this problem by setting the JAVA_HOME variable to the correct path where JRE 1.6 was installed.

But what is the root cause of this error message? The setup actually comes with a bundled JRE and it should not be dependent on any exisiting (pre-installed) JREs...
The JRE search sequence in the install4j project is:
1. installationDir\jre (-> bundled jre)
2. search Windows registry and standard locations
3. Environment variable JAVA_HOME
4. Environment variable JDK_HOME

Many thanks for any help on this...

Regards,
thkampp

Answer (score 0):

When the startup of the JVM fails for some reason, install4j remembers this failure for the next start of the same executable and asks you this question.

To learn more about the cause of the failure, start the executable from command line with the argument

```
/create-i4j-log
```

When the failure occurs, the native log file will contain details that are useful for debugging the root cause.

If it only happens sometimes, you can also define the environment variable

```
INSTALL4j_LOG=yes
```

instead of the command line argument. In that case a new native log file will be silently written to the %TEMP% directory each time you start the executable.